# robotjs is not working on Microsoft edge browser for protractor e2e test

Tags: protractor

am writing an e2e test with protractor framework, one of the test cases has a upload file window dialog where i navigate to the file directory path and select it, for this methodology am using robotjs plugin, it's working fine except two conditions:
 1. If the mouse is on another screen, the tests will fail because the path will be posted on the screen that the mouse points at.
 2. When i tried to include Microsoft edge browser, the robojs will not work for a reason i still don't know, some of the comments indicated that actions like mouseMove will not work on edge.

if anyone has any suggested solution, please don't hesitate to post you opinion.
Thanks in advance.